# How do I force shift up on AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey, undo

I want to change `Ctrl + Shift + Z` to `Ctrl + Y` so I made the below script:

```
^+z::^y
```

This script sends `Ctrl + Shift + Y`, which isn't quite what I want, so I changed it to:

```
^+z::
  KeyWait LShift
  Send ^y
  Return
```

It works, but it causes kind of delay because I should up LShift in order to execute Send line.
Is there any way to avoid this delay?

Comment: Seems like you're probably doing this to change the redo bind in some program. Are you sure you can't just change the bind in the program's settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
^+z::
  Send {Shift up}
  Send ^y
  Return
```

This should programmatically release the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key before Sending the `^y` input.